# Windows 10 printer via NAS and WiFi not working

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, nas

On Windows 10 I have an OKI B410 printer connected via a DLINK DNS-320 NAS with USB port, and this connection has worked fine for some years. The DLINK is connected via WiFi by TP-LINK DECO. All of this has worked fine until around November 2021, but now I have lost connection to the printer. I am not aware that I reconfigured anything (but you never know).

When running Windows Printer Troubleshooting The error message is: ‘Printer Cannot Be Contacted over the Network’

The connection to DLINK NAS drive is fine, the printer icon is visible in the root of the NAS address, but printing does not work. The IP address0020is static.

I have uninstalled and re-installed the printer and the port. Printer Spooler service is running. Remote Access Auto Connection Manager service is also running.

Anybody with helpful input?

Comment: Have you tried printing on the printer while connecting it directly to a PC (to make sure the printer is not faulty)?

Comment: Thanks, USB printing works fine